# export data from div tag to Excel in asp but it fail

Tags: html, excel, tags, export

I want to export data from div tag to Excel in asp, but fails  when i export in excel files only this code.

this is my aspx page

```
<div id="dvInfo" runat="server">
    <table id="thoantat" runat="server" class="tg" style="undefined; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
        <%--<colgroup>
            <col style="width: 123px" />
            <col style="width: 51px" />
            <col style="width: 51px" />
            <col style="width: 50px" />
            <col style="width: 51px" />
            <col style="width: 67px" />
            <col style="width: 51px" />
            <col style="width: 51px" />
            <col style="width: 52px" />
            <col style="width: 52px" />
            <col style="width: 75px" />
        </colgroup>--%>
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2">Đơn vị</th>
            <th class="tg-y56a" colspan="10"><span style="color: lightblue;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label95" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">TS</td>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">CĐ</td>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">GP</td>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">DD</td>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">MEGA</td>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">FIPER</td>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">MYTV</td>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">PHXH</td>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">CA</td>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">EZCOME</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">DTH</td>
            <td class="tg-u227"><span style="color: red;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: blue;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: blue;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: blue;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: blue;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: blue;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: blue;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: blue;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: blue;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: blue;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">DXN</td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label24" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">PHA</td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label30" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label31" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label32" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label33" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label34" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">SCU</td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label35" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label36" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label37" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label38" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label39" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label40" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label41" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label42" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label43" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label44" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">SHA</td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label45" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label46" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label47" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label48" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label49" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label50" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label51" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label52" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label53" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label54" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">SHH</td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label55" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label56" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label57" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label58" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label59" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label60" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label61" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label62" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label63" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label64" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">TAN</td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label65" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label66" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label67" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label68" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label69" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label70" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label71" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label72" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label73" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label74" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">THA</td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label75" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label76" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label77" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label78" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label79" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label80" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label81" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label82" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label83" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <asp:Label ID="Label84" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-wv6k">TS</td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label85" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label86" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label87" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label88" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label89" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label90" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label91" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label92" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label93" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td class="tg-u227">
                <span style="color: red;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label94" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" CssClass="btn btn-info"  OnClick="LinkButton2_Click" runat="server">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/excel.png" />
                &nbsp; Xuất Excel
            </asp:LinkButton>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and code behind

```
 protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        dvInfo.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();  

        //string html = HdnValue.Value;
        //ExportToExcel(ref html, "MyReport");
    }
```

when i click export in file excel only

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dvInfo"> </div>
```

my project using page with master page. thank so much

Comment: Formatted the html code

Comment: Formatted the html code         I DON'T KNOW WHAT THIS YOU SAY